# Are you sure that Ezekiel a word of God ?any clarification?

Tags: ezekiel

This is my last question here , I come up to  Disasters in Bible , In particular in Ezekiel as shown in the below list , The God of Christtians talk about  prostitutes , I do not have any thing to say .  I let you to  comment after reading in each Testament  , Is this a word of God ?  .

(Ezekiel 16:33 )
**All prostitutes receive gifts, but you give gifts to all your lovers, bribing them to come to you from everywhere for your illicit favors**.

(Ezekiel 23:3 )
**They became prostitutes in Egypt, engaging in prostitution from their youth. In that land their breasts were fondled and their virgin bosoms caressed**

(Ezekiel 16:34) New International Version (NIV)

**So in your prostitution you are the opposite of others; no one runs after you for your favors. You are the very opposite, for you give payment and none is given to you**.

(Ezekiel 16:25) New International Version (NIV)

**At every street corner you built your lofty shrines and degraded your beauty, spreading your legs with increasing promiscuity to anyone who passed by**

...............................................................

**Conclusion: **So woe to those who write the "scripture" with their own hands, then say, "This is from Allah," in order to exchange it for a small price. Woe to them for what their hands have written and woe to them for what they earn**

لااله الا الله محمد رسول الله واستغفر الله العظيم

Comment: Sorry, what about these verses means they couldn't be the word of God? God says his relationship with Israel is like a marriage, and that when Israel worshipped idols they were like someone who has sex with a prostitute instead of their spouse. It's a really powerful metaphor. Why do you think it couldn't be the word of God?

Comment: "Disasters," lol---you mean big faux pas? So Ezekiel got a small price? Maybe some bread?

Comment: Throughout Scripture, the relationship between God and Israel is compared with familial ones, such as father and child, or husband and wife. Whenever Israel falls into idolatry, this is comparable to a disobedient child, or a cheating wife.

Comment: Is this a word of God " At every street corner you built your lofty shrines and degraded your beauty, spreading your legs with increasing promiscuity to anyone who passed by" , Is your God decrease at this bad level ? This is not a word of God but the word of baptise and priest who they seek for  prostitutes

Answer (score 3):

It is unwise to take verses out of context.  The prophet Ezekiel was told by God to warn Israel because they had become unfaithful to God in a spiritual sense.  Here, prostitution is likened to the unfaithfulness of Israel.  Just as God condemns prostitution, so God condemns idolatry and turning to false gods.  You ask if the words spoken by Ezekiel the words given to him by God.  Yes.

> “And you shall speak my words to them, whether they hear or refuse to hear, for they are a rebellious house” (Ezekiel 2:7).

Did Ezekiel flinch from delivering the words of condemnation and judgment God told him to deliver to the rebellious and idolatrous nation?  No, because God had laid this command upon him:

> “If I say to the wicked, O wicked one, you shall surely die, and you do not speak to warn the wicked to turn from his way, that wicked person shall die in his iniquity, but his blood I will require at your hand.  But if you warn the wicked to turn from his way, and he does not turn from his way, that person shall die in his iniquity, but you will have delivered your soul” (Ezekiel 33:8-9).

Does God ever flinch from speaking strong words?  Does God pretend that human behaviour can be “swept under the carpet” and ignored just because it is unpleasant?  No.  Throughout the Bible God speaks through his prophets to condemn immorality – whether it is physical or spiritual.  The Bible is full of warnings against prostitution.  The Bible tells us that prostitution is immoral.

> "For a prostitute is a deep pit and a wayward wife is a narrow well. Like a bandit she lies in wait, and multiplies the unfaithful among men" (Proverbs 23:27-28)

God forbids involvement with prostitutes because He knows such involvement is detrimental to both men and women.

> For the lips of an immoral woman drip honey, and her mouth is smoother than oil; But in the end she is bitter as wormwood, Sharp as a two-edged sword. Her feet go down to death, her steps lay hold of hell" (Proverbs 5:3-5 NKJV).

Prostitution not only destroys marriages, families, and lives, but it destroys the spirit and soul in a way that leads to physical and spiritual death. God’s desire is that we stay pure and use our bodies as tools for His use and glory (Romans 6:13).

Did Ezekiel speak the words of God?  Yes.  God hates immorality, prostitution and idolatry.  Strong language was required to warn Israel of the dangerous path they were on.  That is why their unfaithfulness to God was likened to prostitution – and unless they heeded God’s warnings, their conduct would be punished.

God does not hesitate to expose sinful behaviour and condemn it.  Those verses in Ezekiel liken the sinful conduct of Israel to that of a prostitute.  Context is everything.

Just one final point that needs to be made here – Ezekiel was not speaking the words of Allah.  Ezekiel was speaking the words of Yahweh.

Comment: Lesley:  A very powerful answer +1 I wish I could make it 10. Please note what Ezekiel 23:4 says: "Their names were Oholah the elder and Oholibah her sister. And they became Mine, and they bore sons and daughters. And as for their names, Samaria is Oholah, and Jerusalem is Oholibah." (NASB ) Of course, at the time the older sister Oholah and the younger sister Oholibah began prostituting themselves in Egypt, the northern kingdom of Israel and the southern kingdom of Judah had not come into existence. But the tribes of Israel that eventually made up those kingdoms did exist.

Comment: @Ozzie Nicolas Appreciate the additional information in your comment

Comment: Yahweh means Allah in Hebrew language

Comment: In Hebrew God’s name is four consonants – YHWH. There are no vowels.The name refers to God’s self-existence and is linked to how God described Himself in Exodus 3:14: “God said to Moses, I AM WHO I AM. This is what you are to say to the Israelites: I AM has sent me to you.” God’s name is a reflection of His being. God is the only self-existent or self-sufficient Being. Only God has life in and of Himself. That is the essential meaning of the tetragrammaton, YHWH. I know Muslims claim the God of Abraham is Allah but but the name Allah nowhere exists in any Hebrew or Greek biblical manuscript.